# javascript : how can I use "$(this)" in eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, eval

In my application, I am using eval to run javascript code received via ajax.

I want to be able to use $(this) in the javascript sent via eval so it be used in the code where it is executed. The real aim is to apply some of the eval code to a closest parent from where it is executed :

```
$('.json').on('click', function(){ $.ajax(
//my stuff
).success(eval(text_received_via_ajax))});
```

and I want to have in the text_received_via_ajax the following :

```
$(this).closest('.button').doSomething
```

where $(this) is the actual $('.json') element clicked.

How can I do that ?
Thanks !

Comment: Don't use `eval` there must be other way to achieve the same result.

Comment: well, I'm rendering a custom javascript with twig, with parameters rendered in the code, I don't see another way yet. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: well, I finally thought a little bit harder and followed the good advices given here. i'm now just sending parameters so I don't need eval anymore. thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing code like this, then it strongly implies that your software design is bad.

You *really* don't need to use `eval()`. Not for this, and really not for anything else either.

In your case, I suggest looking into [jQuery's `getScript` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

This method allows you to load a new Javascript file on-demand at a given point in your code. This would replace the Ajax call that you're making now.

You'd probably also need to modify the code that you're loading so that it is written as a callable function rather than an open block of JS code. You can then simply call, it passing in `this` (or binding it, as you prefer), without any need to use `eval()`.

Much simpler, cleaner code: easier to read, easier to maintain, less vulnerable to bugs and hacks, and you should get better performance out of it too.

Comment: What I did was I built a popup making an ajax call to render a twig view allowing to create an object so that the user is not redirected when he needs a new object that does not exist in the dropdown he is selectingelements from. When submitting the form, the object is created and the javascript response is customized so that the reference to the object is added to the right select. When there is only one select in the page, that's fine I can pass the id. But when there are more I need to use $(this). Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: It's hard to give a better answer than I've given already without a bit more context and seeing more of your code. You might want to consider editing the question (or even just create a new one) to give a bit more of the underlying detail.

Comment: well, I finally thought a little bit harder and followed the good advices given here. i'm now just sending parameters so I don't need eval anymore. thanks !

Comment: Excellent  :)  I'm glad I could be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

via `.bind(this)`

```
$('.json').on('click', function(){ $.ajax(
  //my stuff
).success(eval(text_received_via_ajax.bind(this))});
```

This will inject the this-context into that function. See here for [more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors in your code, the eval become:

```
$.ajax({...}).success($(this).closest('.button').doSomething());
```

The above piece of code will work but not as expected because do something will be called, and the output from the function call, will then be assigned as the success handler.

And how can you eval before you get the value from the request? You will need to make a callback that can eval for you:

```
$.ajax({...}).success(function(text_received_via_ajax) {
  eval(text_received_via_ajax);
});
```

But wait! Now the context (`this`) is wrong because `this` inside the handler will become the ajax request. To fix this you will need to bind the context of the handler using:

```
function() { console.log(this === newContext); }.bind(newContext)
```

Or for older browser jQuery provides `$.proxy(fn, newContext)`:

```
$('.json').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({...}).success($.proxy(function(text_received_via_ajax) {
    eval(text_received_via_ajax);
  }, this));
```

#### But please reconsider using `eval` in the first place!

You might be able to come up with some sort of definition on how your program should behave and send that definition instead, eg:

```
{
  'doSomething': true,
  'selector': '.button'
}
```

And then handle it like this:

```
var def = { /* the above definition */ }
var $el = $(this).closest(def.selector);

if ( def.doSomething ) $el.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fair word of warning: Using eval is dangerous, be sure you know what you are doing

As eval works on the global scope, you will have to utilise the global scope to achieve what you want to achieve.

From my point of view there are two ways to do so:
1. Wrap your eval-code into a named function which you execute after the eval call
2. Save this in a global variable with a specific name, which is then used inside of the eval-code

Example for 1:

```
var evalString = "console.log(this);"
var random = Math.random();
var changedEvalString = "function _reference_this() {" +
                          evalString +
                        "}"
eval(changedEvalString); //does not execute a thing
_reference_this.apply(this); //calls your code with the correct this
```

Example for 2:

```
window._saved_this = this;
eval("console.log(_saved_this)")
```

I think solution 1 is a lot cleaner, but solution 2 might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Json element returned which value ?
returned element id or class value ?

if yes you can use addEventListener method for it or bind or equal

```
$('.json').on('click', function(){

$this = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _url,
        data: 'id=' + data_item,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (ReturnedJSON) {

$($this).addEventListener('click',function(){
do somethings...
});

$(ReturnedJSON).addEventListener('click',function(){
do somethings...
});

// --- OR ---

$($this).click(function(){
do somethings...
});

$(ReturnedJSON).click(function(){
do somethings...
});

    });

});
```

i use $this val. for Ajax method is async so need a carrier val
or you can add this parameter on ajax props.
""  async: false  ""

OR lite another code here

```
var JSON = $.ajax({
dataType: 'JSON',
type: 'POST',
async: false,   ---- if this prop have on ajax method. Javascript waiting complate event for next rows.
url: 'GetModel',
data: 'brand=' + $brand

            }).responseJSON;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the event parameter in an anonymous function you can access the element with class '.json' which fired the event:

```
$('.json').on('click', function(event) {
    $.ajax().success(
        eval(text_received_via_ajax)
        $(event.target).closest('.button').doSomething
)});
```